# Modifying a container within std::for_each

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Does the Standard explicitly forbid modifying a container within `std::for_each`?

More specifically, in case of `std::list` iterators are not invalidated when the list is modified. Thus, the following code works:

```
std::list<int> list;

list.push_front(5);
list.push_front(10);
auto it = list.end();
it--; // point to 5

std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [&](int i){
    /* the line below will remove the last element in the list;
     * list will have only one element (the currently processed one);
     * list.end() is not invalidated and we exit for_each() */
    list.erase(it);
});
```

This is definitely a bad code. But is it legal?

Comment: This question should be much more upvoted, really...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the Standard explicitly forbid modifying a container within `std::for_each`?

The only thing I can think of that would make this code not standard compliant is that in `[alg.foreach]` we have

> *Complexity:* Applies `f` exactly `last - first` times.

<sup>`f` being the function `for_each` applies.</sup>

Since the list is modified and an element is removed we no longer satisfy that complexity.  I do not know if that make it non conforming but it is the only thing I could see that would not allow you to remove elements from the container while using `for_each`

Answer (score 3):

> Does the Standard explicitly forbid modifying a container within
>   `std::for_each`?

No, not **explicitly**. At least for any sensible definition of "explicitly". The section on `std::for_each` (§25.2.4) does not say anything at all about iterator invalidation or side effects that cause modification of the iterated range.

There are, however, plenty of **implicit** reasons for why your code cannot work. Consider how `std::for_each` must be implemented. It's completely generic and therefore does not know anything about the `std::list` it operates on; you gave it two iterators to form a range, which means that `last` can be reached from `first`. How should `std::for_each` know that your function object has invalidated the local iterator object with which it goes from `first` to `last`?

And even if the function knew that invalidation has occurred, what should it do? In a hand-written loop, you'd take the result of `erase` and continue iteration with it, but `std::for_each` cannot do that, by definition.

Here's an old but still valid reference article: http://www.drdobbs.com/effective-standard-c-library-foreach-vs/184403769

It says:

> For instance, invalidating the iterators or the sequences that the
>   algorithm works with is disastrous in any case. Even the function
>   object supplied to for_each must obey this common-sense rule, even if
>   the Standard does not say so.

---

Paraphrasing some wise words I once read:

*The C++ standard is written by human beings; it's not always as perfect as we wish it to be.*

Answer (score 2):

Your code is borderline legal.

With the posted code, it is legal by coincidence. If you add one more item to the list, your program will crash.

Try the following to see the problem:

```
int main()
{
   std::list<int> list;

   list.push_front(5);
   list.push_front(10);
   list.push_front(12);
   auto it = list.end();
   it--; // point to 5

   std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [&](int i){
                 /* the line below will remove the last element in the list;
                  * list will have only one element (the currently processed one);
                  * list.end() is not invalidated and we exit for_each() */
                 list.erase(it);
                 });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will erase the same iterator twice, which is not allowed. But the question remains, is it conceptually allowed to modify the container or does it trigger some kind of UB?

Comment: It is UB to call erase twice using the same iterator since the first call to erase makes the iterator invalid.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I am asking. Assume, it is ensured that the iterator is not erased twice. Is it still an UB?

Comment: @Kane, in that case, I am not following your question. The key point is that it is UB to use an iterator that has been erased. If your code does not use an iterator after it has been erased, than it is valid and should not result in UB.

Comment: It is not just about my code not using an iterator after it is invalidated. It is also about `std::for_each` not using it after it is invalidated.

Comment: @Kane, I was implying that. `std::for_each` call the last argument with each value in the range `[first, last)`. Unless you call erase on the current iterator that `std::for_each` is using, you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

25.2.4/2:

> Effects: Applies f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the
>   range [first,last), starting from first and proceeding to last - 1.

Then 25.2.4/4:

> Complexity: Applies f exactly last - first times.

I'm prepared to argue that these two points explicitly prohibit mutating the container in a way that changes the number of elements.

That said, even it doesn't your example fails if the list has even one more item, OR if your standard library implementation increments the iterator before calling your function (and I can't see anything in the standard that prohibits such an implementation).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's legal. There's const iters if you need something that is guaranteed not to modify the underlying container.

Comment: Proof? If it is not an `std::list` or I delete an iterator to the currently processed element, it is going to crash.

Comment: Then please define "legal". I meant: does this code comply with the Standard or does it work just by accident?